# How to get errors from solved basin-hopping results (using Powell method for local)

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I traditionally like to use BFGS or L-BFGS because it reports the inverse-hessian for errors. However I've noticed other solvers such as Nelder-Mead and Powell, do not report the inverse-hessian. The same is true of Basin Hopping.

In a scenario where you are using Basin Hopping with Powell as the local minimizer, how would one go about trying to find the error of the solution?

Say you had an input such as this

```
basinhopping(fun,minimizer_kwargs={"args":(input1,input2),"method" : 'Powell',"bounds":(0,np.inf)}, x0=1.0)
```

With an output such as this

```
 message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
                    success: True
                        fun: 2.9445950465323385
                          x: [ 9.349e+03]
                        nit: 100
      minimization_failures: 0
                       nfev: 10141
 lowest_optimization_result: message: Optimization terminated successfully.
                             success: True
                              status: 0
                                 fun: 2.9445950465323385
                                   x: [ 9.349e+03]
                                 nit: 5
                               direc: [[ 1.805e+03]
                                       [ 2.962e+03]]
                                nfev: 175
```

So the solution is 9.349e3 with a chi2 of 2.944, but what is the error of 9.349e3? i.e. 9.349+/-?

**Edit:**

So attempting to use your solution, I think I have it setup properly?

```
from statsmodels.base.optimizer import _fit_powell 
from statsmodels.tools.numdiff import approx_hess1
from numpy.linalg import inv
import numpy as np

solution=_basinhopping(fun,minimizer_kwargs={"args":(input1,input2),"method" : 'Powell',"bounds":(0,np.inf)}, x0=1.0)
hessian=approx_hess(solution.x,fun,args=(input1,input2))
print(np.diag(inv(hessian))
```

So just wanted to confirm this is the proper method/setup for error determination. I.E. You calculate the hessian with finite differences, then take inverse diagonal for the errors for your values. Again there are no examples, so while this works, I don't know if I have the code written properly/setup correctly.

The only other question I have however is, is this not for determining the differential? I.E. For error propagation you also need a covariance matrix?

```
[df/dx df/dy][covariance matrix][df/dx df/dy]^T
```

So how does one calculate the variances for this? Or is the inverse hessian the variance?

Comment: `powell` doesn't calculate or use a Hessian. Therefore, if you use it as a local minimiser with `basinhopping` you won't get any Hessian related information returned.

Comment: To obtain a Hessian from a scalar function you can use something like `approx_hess2` from https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/tools/numdiff.py

Comment: @AndrewNelson thank you for the link, this makes things a lot easier (thought I might have to make my own). However, I am a touch confused on how to use this. From what I can see, it appears you use the solver not through scipy, but through statsmodel itself. I also can't find any examples they have setup for the terminology for optimization. For example this link has the details https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.base.optimizer._fit_powell.html, and I can see an option to call the Hessian, but no examples (or how to call the Hessian, since there are multiple

Comment: methods in their toolset). Would it be possible to just enter an example input using the basin hopping with Powell that i have setup above (just one line so I can get an idea for the format used) for saying calculating the Hessian with finite difference derivative approximation?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you need to use statsmodels to do the minimisation. Rather, once you've done the minimisation with e.g. `optimize.basinhopping`, you can try to estimate the Hessian with one of statsmodels functions. In my codebase I use approx_hess2 from statsmodels to figure out the Hessian, and hence the parameter uncertainties. So it's something you do after the minimisation.
You already have what you need to call that function, `res.x` and the objective function.

Another package for estimating Hessians would be numdifftools.

Comment: @AndrewNelson thank you for the feedback. Can you confirm the edits that I have made in the original post are the correct setup then? I.E. This the proper way to use statsmodels for calculating errors of minimized values?

Comment: I would use approx_hess2